# Using zip_longest to sum different length lists and fill different lengths from start rather than end

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have two lists `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3]`

I would like to sum these to give me the following: `[1,3,5,7]`.

This was done by doing `1+0=1`, `2+1=3`, `3+2=5` and `4+3=7`.

I understand that `itertools.zip_longest` would do this, but it would fill the mismatch in length with `0` at the end, giving me `[2,3,6,4]` and not the value I want.

I would like the mismatch in length to be solved by filling the first length with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function could be used to do it like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest    

def sum_lists(*iterables):
    iterables = (reversed(it) for it in iterables)
    return list(reversed([a+b for a, b in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=0)]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = sum_lists([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3])
    print(result)  # -> [1, 3, 5, 7]
    result = sum_lists([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
    print(result)  # -> [1, 3, 5, 7]    # Order of args doesn't matter.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the second list with zeros and use `zip`:

```
s1, s2 = [1,2,3,4], [1, 2, 3]
new_result = [a+b for a, b in zip(s1, ([0]*(len(s1)-len(s2)))+s2)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: This is assuming that `s2` is always the shorter list, `zip_longest` will determine which is shorter. Not a bad solution, but would likely need one previous step to determine which list to pad in the front.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reversed` function to generate the two lists in reverse order so that `zip_longest` would align the zipping from the other end, and then reverse the result afterwards:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
lists = [1,2,3,4], [1, 2, 3]
print(list(map(sum, zip_longest(*map(reversed, lists), fillvalue=0)))[::-1])
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: does not differ much from mine, does it?

Comment: I saw yours after I posted mine. They're indeed the same in idea, but since mine is somewhat more generalized in that it can accommodate multiple lists, I decided to leave mine here.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a *shift* by using [repeat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), then concatenate the shift with the shorter one using [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

first = [1, 2, 3, 4]
second = [1, 2, 3]

shift = repeat(0, abs(len(first) - len(second)))

result = [a + b for a, b in zip(first, chain(shift, second))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go around this problem be *reversing* your lists befor `zip`ing with `zip_longest`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s1, s2 = [1,2,3,4], [1, 2, 3]
res = [a+b for a, b in zip_longest(reversed(s1), reversed(s2), fillvalue=0)]
```

and finally, *reverse* again, to produce the desired result:

```
res = res[::-1]
print(res)  # [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

---

The main advantage of this method as @CoryKramer says in his comment is that you do not have to know beforehand which list is the longest.