# Multiple array of digits for processing big integers

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, constants

I processing really big numbers, integers, with 10000 digits, so I split each number to array.

Small data sample:

```
#all combinations with length 3 of values in list L
N = 3
L = [[1,9,0]]*N
a = np.array(np.meshgrid(*L)).T.reshape(-1,N)
#it is number so removed first 0 and also last value is always 0
a = a[(a[:, 0] != 0) & (a[:, -1] == 0)]
print (a)
[[1 1 0]
 [1 9 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [9 1 0]
 [9 9 0]
 [9 0 0]]
```

Then I need multiple number by 1.1 scalar. For better understanding:

```
#joined arrays to numbers
b = np.array([int(''.join(x)) for x in a.astype(str)])[:, None]
print (b)
[[110]
 [190]
 [100]
 [910]
 [990]
 [900]]

#multiple by constant
c = b * 1.1
print (c)
[[ 121.]
 [ 209.]
 [ 110.]
 [1001.]
 [1089.]
 [ 990.]]
```

But because 10000 digits, this solution is not possible, because rounding. So I need solution for multiple in arrays:

What I try: Added last 0 'column' to first and then sum:

```
a1 = np.hstack((a[:, [-1]] , a[:, :-1] ))
print (a1)
[[0 1 1]
 [0 1 9]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 9 1]
 [0 9 9]
 [0 9 0]]

print (a1 + a)
[[ 1  2  1]
 [ 1 10  9]
 [ 1  1  0]
 [ 9 10  1]
 [ 9 18  9]
 [ 9  9  0]]
```

But problem is if value is more like `9` is necessary shift next digits (like old school paper summing), expected output is:

```
c1 = np.array([list(str(x).split('.')[0].zfill(4)) for x in np.ravel(c)]).astype(int)
print (c1)
[[0 1 2 1]
 [0 2 0 9]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 8 9]
 [0 9 9 0]]
```

Is possible some fast vectorized solution for generate `c1` array from `a` array?

EDIT: I try another data for testing and solution by @yatu raise error:

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

---

```
from itertools import product,zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

#real data
#M = 100000
#N = 500
#loop by chunks by length 5
M = 20
N = 5
v = [0]*M
for i in grouper(product([9, 0], repeat=M), N, v):
    a = np.array(i)
#    print (a)
    #it is number so removed first 0 and also last value is always 0
    a = a[(a[:, 0] != 0) & (a[:, -1] == 0)]
    print (a)
#

    s = np.arange(a.shape[1]-1, -1, -1)
    # concat digits along cols, and multiply
    b = (a * 10**s).sum(1)*1.1
    # highest amount of digits in b
    n_cols = int(np.log10(b.max()))
    # broadcast division to reverse
    c = b[:, None] // 10**np.arange(n_cols, -1, -1)
    # keep only last digit
    c1 = (c%10).astype(int)
    print (c1)
```

Comment: @ScottBoston - It is numpy, not easy ;) Unfortunately pandas is slow here... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one working from `a`. The idea is to multiply each column by `10**seq`, `seq` being an arange up to the number of columns, and in descending order. This will act as a *concatenation* of the digits along the columns once we take the `sum` along the second axis. 
Finally we can reverse the process by applying the same logic but dividing instead and broadcasting to the resulting shape after multiplying by `1.1`, and taking the modulo 10 of the result to keep only the last digit:

```
s = np.arange(a.shape[1]-1, -1, -1, dtype=np.float64)
# concat digits along cols, and multiply
b = (a * 10**s).sum(1)*1.1
# highest amount of digits in b
n_cols = int(np.log10(b.max()))
# broadcast division to reverse
c = b[:, None] // 10**np.arange(n_cols, -1, -1, dtype=np.float64)
# keep only last digit
c1 = (c%10).astype(int)
```

---

```
print(c1)

array([[0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 9],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 8, 9],
       [0, 9, 9, 0]])
```

---

Update -

The above approach works for integers no higher than the supported for `int64`, which is:

```
np.iinfo(np.int64).max
# 9223372036854775807
```

However, what *can*  be done in such cases is to save the arrays values as python `int` rather than a numpy `dtype`. So we could define both `np.arange` to be of `dtype` object, and the above should work for the shared example:

```
s = np.arange(a.shape[1]-1, -1, -1, dtype=object)
# concat digits along cols, and multiply
b = (a * 10**s).sum(1)*1.1
# highest amount of digits in b
n_cols = int(np.log10(b.max()))
# broadcast division to reverse
c = b[:, None] // 10**np.arange(n_cols, -1, -1, dtype=object)
# keep only last digit
c1 = (c%10).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but unfortunately there is some bug, answer was edited with some another data for generate error. Please check it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, let me check @jez

Comment: Overflow error when using the array `a = np.array([[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0],  [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 0]])` @jez . Another way to combine all cols into an int could be `a.astype('U1').view(f'U{a.shape[1]}').astype(np.int64)`, but you see that the error is explicit here: `OverflowError: int too big to convert`. So basically you can't operate on that int since it is too large even for `int64`

Comment: Yes, for this size the approach suggested in the question would not work @jez

Comment: Updated with a workaround @jezrael let me know if it works

Comment: Also check with `dtype=np.float64` (update on the first version) might also work for you

Comment: I tested it with `M = 10000 and N = 100` and get errors, `ValueError: Maximum allowed size exceeded` if used `np.float64`, else with `object` is error `OverflowError: int too large to convert to float` :(

Comment: My loopy solution `def sum11(a):
    out = []
    a = list(a)
    b = a[:-1]
    carry = 0
    for ca, cb in zip_longest(reversed(a), reversed(b), fillvalue=0):
        carry, digit = divmod(ca + cb + carry, 10)
        out.append(str(digit))
    fin = out + [1]  if out[-1] == '0' else out
    return sum(int(c) for c in fin)`

Comment: It is something similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185172/2901002), solution working because multiple by 1.1 is same like add shifted values, because last 0 always

Comment: Hmm will give it a look @jez shame it cannot be vectorized in this way :(

Comment: I use your idea and working with `Decimal`, so your answer was helpful for me. thank you.